# public pages migration from 6.2 ee to Liferay 7.0

Tags: migration, liferay, liferay-7

As part of upgrade from Liferay 6.2 EE to Liferay 7.0, i am looking for a solution on migration of public/private pages with structure and template.

What are possible ways to achieve this task ? pls suggest.

- Issue details are as below:

I need to export all public pages which are developed using template language (.vm) from LIferay 6.2 EE to Liferay 7

**Approaches tried so far and exception:**

1) I exported a lar with few public pages from 6.2 EE and changed manifest.xml and tried to import it into Liferay DXP. This DIDN'T work as got exception as **"$UnknowFieldException: No Such Field com.liferay.portal.model.impl.LayoutImpl._userUuid ..."**

Comment: This question is too broad,

See

Comment: agreed - plus: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Answer (score 1):

This is not as broad as the comment suggest, simply because: export and import functionally is not supported across versions, as the xml underneath has different formats across LR releases - if you look in your database you will see it.

If you to go trough an upgrade process, please follow the upgrade procedures described to upgrade your database first: those using the upgrade tool (lr_home/tools). After bringing your database to the correct version, you will be able to use import and export again. But you also have to bear in mind that vm templates might have pieces that are no longer available or simple have a different names, in some cases you just need to change their names to the new ones - some are just in different packages.

https://dev.liferay.com/pt/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/breaking-changes

ps: the exception described is a typical symptom of different xml formats for a given structure, btw.